# How to apply iOS Object Tree Optimization in the robotframework

Tags: javascript, appium, robotframework

I'm experiencing performance issues with the iOS object tree. It keeps loading indefinitely. I need to set the maximum number of child UI elements retrieved for each element node. However, when I do it in my Robot Framework code, I get the following error: Keyword 'AppiumLibrary.Execute Script' received an unexpected named argument 'children'.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eW1nY.png)

I tried the tutorial: https://help.perfecto.io/perfecto-help/content/perfecto/legacy/legacy___ios_object_tree_optimization.htm
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMvCh.png)